# How to enable cuda unified memory in tensorflow v2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In `tensorflow` 1.x, there is an option like `use_unified_memory` and `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` which is potential to trigger CUDA UVM used. But how can this be done in `tensorflow` 2.0?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto

```
// If true, uses CUDA unified memory for memory allocations. If
// per_process_gpu_memory_fraction option is greater than 1.0, then unified
// memory is used regardless of the value for this field. See comments for
// per_process_gpu_memory_fraction field for more details and requirements
// of the unified memory. This option is useful to oversubscribe memory if
// multiple processes are sharing a single GPU while individually using less
// than 1.0 per process memory fraction.
bool use_unified_memory = 2;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 2
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

Comment: Why do you use `2` in gpu_memory_fraction? As far as I know, It should be less than 1.

Comment: So you can use your system ram in addition to the gpu memory . If your gpu has 2 GB of memory, it can start allocating 4 GB (factor of 2) or 6 GB (factor of 3) , etc. However  it will make the training process slower.

Comment: Use value lager than 1 will force it to use unified memory.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unified memory on GPUs with compute capability lower than 6.0 (pre-Pascal class GPUs) does not support oversubscription.` What does this mean?

Comment: `compute capability lower than 6.0` means you are using GPUs older than Pascal micro-
architecture.  See this list: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute

Answer (score 3):

If someone's looking to enable UVM in 1.x, just set the `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` over 1 (to any number you want).

`use_unified_memory` doesn't do anything.

Another potential bug of TensorFlow: you may want to move your model definition to after you establish the session. Like

```py
with tf.Session(GPUOptions...) as s:
    model = xxx
    s.run(model)
```