# Why does my model which uses Tenserflow and Keras GPU OOM error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to run my model but i am running intro an error

```
2021-06-03 01:20:42.015864: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:467] **************************************************************************__________________________
2021-06-03 01:20:42.015984: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at concat_op.cc:158 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8938,46080] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[8938,46080] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from cv2 import cv2
from keras.applications.densenet import preprocess_input
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool2D, MaxPool3D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Reshape, GlobalMaxPooling2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, AveragePooling2D

# physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
# print("Num GPU Available", len(physical_devices))
# tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

train_path = 'data/train'
test_path = 'data/test'
batch_size = 16
image_size = (360, 360)

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
    # rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rotation_range=.3,
    width_shift_range=.2,
    height_shift_range=.2,
    zoom_range=.2
).flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
                      target_size=image_size,
                      color_mode='rgb',
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      shuffle=True)

test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
    # rescale=1./255
).flow_from_directory(directory=test_path,
                      target_size=image_size,
                      color_mode='rgb',
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      shuffle=True)

# mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet()
mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(360, 360, 3))

x = MaxPool2D()(mobile.layers[-1].output)
x = Flatten()(x)
model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=x)

train_features = model.predict(train_batches, train_batches.labels)
test_features = model.predict(test_batches, test_batches.labels)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train_features)
test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(test_features)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svm = SVC()

svm.fit(train_scaled, train_batches.labels)

print('train accuracy:')
print(svm.score(train_scaled, train_batches.labels))
print('test accuracy:')
print(svm.score(test_scaled, test_batches.labels))
```

Comment: This link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16768 might help

Answer (score 0):

This error is Out Of Memory.
Try to reduce the value of `batch_size`.

Comment: I've tried this and it seems it doesn't want to work.

I dont really understand the problem, but a friend who tried to run the model on their laptop and it works, even though they have lesser specs than me. I just hope my GPU is not faulty or something.

Answer (score 0):

If reducing batch_size value does not solve the issue. You can enable cuda unified memory. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58025069/how-to-enable-cuda-unified-memory-in-tensorflow-v2#answer-59798962)

Comment: I tried to enable cuda unflied memory by decomenting these lines
`# physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
# print("Num GPU Available", len(physical_devices))
# tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
`
however, this didn't solve the problem, as it keeps crashing
Running on the cpu also doesn't work.

Comment: Setting the batch_size to 8, also doesn't work.

Comment: @bSwizzle Can you try the input shape that match your pre-trained model. I have not tried it. Please have a look. to be specified  the input shape should be (224, 224, 3) not input_shape=(360, 360, 3). https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/MobileNetV2